# Is there any way to turn a uvec into vec?

Tags: armadillo

wanna do this:

```
#include <armadillo>


int main(){    
    arma::mat mat=arma::randn(5,5);    
    mat.each_col( [](arma::vec& vec){
        vec=arma::sort_index(vec);
    } );          
    return 0;
```

Is there any way to turn a uvec into vec?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `arma::conv_to<DesiredType>::from(value)`.

See below

```cpp
#include <armadillo>


int main(){
    arma::mat mat=arma::randn(5,5);

    mat.print("mat");

    mat.each_col( [](arma::vec& vec){
                      vec = arma::conv_to<arma::vec>::from(arma::sort_index(vec));
                  } );

    mat.print("mat");

    return 0;
}
```

With this we can convert the output of `arma::sort_index`, which is an `arma::uvec`, into an `arma::vec` and the assignment will work.

Comment: Thanks pal! that's so useful!

Comment: I'm glad to help. If it fully answers your question then you should accept the answer.

Comment: sorry man！I am new to here 。。how to accept。。I find that button ！！